# set $PATH on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iphone 4s running 7.1.2 and I downloaded the IOS Tool chain from cydia. while trying to run the configure script for libressl i get...

```
 Nah-Niggass-iPhone:/User/libressl-2.0.5 root# ./configure
 checking build system type... arm-apple-darwin14.0.0
 checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin14.0.0
 checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
 checking whether build environment is sane... yes
 checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
 checking for gawk... no
 checking for mawk... no
 checking for nawk... no
 checking for awk... no
 checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
 checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
 checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
 checking for style of include used by make... GNU
 checking for gcc... no
 checking for cc... no
 checking for cl.exe... no
 configure: error: in `/User/libressl-2.0.5':
 configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
 See `config.log' for more details
```

So I added these lines to /etc/profile

```
 PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/opt/csw/sbin:/opt/csw/gcc3/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin:/usr/sfw/bin:/opt/csw/mysql5/bin"
 export PATH
```

But I still get the same error. I then checked config.log and it's show's the correct Path to clang

```
 PATH: /usr/bin/clang
```

So How do i get ./configure working on a iphone?

Comment: There's a space in `/usr/local/sbin/` in your question.  Is that in your profile file, too?  Please be careful when posting your question, because these things matter.  And, for crying out loud ... who is voting to close this question as off-topic?  Getting your compiler working is as on-topic for a programming site as it gets.

Comment: @Nate huh. Interesting. I wonder why it's different to OS X? I wish we could edit comments... deleted it instead, since I don't want to be spreading miss-information.

Comment: No i don't have a space in the /etc/profile on the phone i must of messed up copying to the question.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, I agree that there's usually good consistency between OS X and iOS.  Occasionally, though, Apple seems to configure them differently.  I did check, and `/etc/profile` gets executed, while `/etc/.profile/` does not.

Comment: @Nate it's not just OS X/iOS, `.profile` is executed on every UNIX based system I've ever worked with. There doesn't seem to be any reason for Apple to do something different since this only even applies to jail broken devices.